Cherry Blossom Spell & Multi-Hit Spells
How does Cherry Blossom metamagic work with Multi-Hit spells, such as, but not exclusive to:

Magic Missile / Battering Blast
Scorching Ray,
Cluster Bomb Fireball.

Cherry Blossom metamagic description says:

When a living creature takes damage from the affected spell, that creature also takes 2 points of damage to Strength, Dexterity, and Constitution or 2 points of damage to Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma (your choice).

...which to me would mean that if spell deals damage multiple times it also applies Cherry Blossom effect multiple times.
Another thing is, if it works as I think it does:

How many times should Save be rolled if original spell didn't allow save at all?
What happens if original spell was Saved against but half damage still went through, like it's the case with Fireball?

And how will it work with spells that deal damage over several turns like for example Acid Arrow?
Only RAW answers.

I am going to apply the same rules that affects sneak attack on multi-hit spells.
There is an FAQ which sadly says no, but check out my similar question and its answer with some other spells.

Sorry, but as I pointed out in OP, I'm looking for RAW answers. What you wrote has nothing to do with RAW, starting with your very wording "I'm going to..." which already implies a house rule or GM call, neither of which is tolerated in "RAW only" games.

@NecXelos While it is generally okay to provide non-RAW answers even when OP specifically wants RAW answers, such answers should be adequately supported with play experience and helpful reasons for deviating from the RAW answer. This answer doesn’t provide that.
